# Win 11 context menu registry add item

Tags: shell, registry, contextmenu, windows-11

In windows 10 I was able to add positions to the context menu through the registry:
`.../directory/background/shell`

I know I can still do it and access them via `Show More Options`

But I would now like to add them to the new context menu.

I see Windows Terminal has done it, so it has to be possible – but how?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I found out that it is only possible to do it in the app's code.
You can find out more searching for [SparseManifest](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2021/07/19/extending-the-context-menu-and-share-dialog-in-windows-11/)